# Combine two canvas. Put the first on the second

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics, 3d, webgl

I'm trying to do something like this abstraction.

https://www.ciklum.com

As I understand it, need to combine the two `canvas`, put them on top of each other. But how to do it all?

Here I have two implementations, for example.
First

```js
let vertices = [];
let gl = particle.getContext('webgl');
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());

resize();

function resize() {
  
  particle.width = innerWidth;
  particle.height = innerHeight;
  
  let step = 10,
      w = Math.floor(particle.width/step), 
      h = Math.floor(particle.height/step);
  
  vertices = [];
  for (var x=0; x<w*3; x++) 
    for (var y=0; y<10; y++) 
      vertices.push(1/w + x*10/w - 5, 1/h + y*2/h - 1)

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

let pid = gl.createProgram();

shader(`
  attribute vec2 v; 
  uniform float time; 
  varying vec3 c; 

  mat3 rotateX(float a) {
    return mat3(vec3( 1.0,     0.0,    0.0), 
                vec3( -1.0,  cos(a), -sin(a)),
                vec3( 0.0,  sin(a),  cos(a)));
  }
  
  mat3 rotateY(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), 0.0, sin(a)), 
                vec3(    0.0, 1.0,    0.0),
                vec3(-sin(a), 0.0, cos(a)));
  }

  mat3 rotateZ(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), -sin(a),  0.0), 
                vec3( sin(a),  cos(a),  0.0),
                vec3(    0.0,     0.0,  1.0));
  }
  
  void main(void) {
    vec2 p = v;
    p.y += 0.3;
    p.x += sin(time/4. + p.y);
    vec3 pos = vec3(p.xy, 0.0)*rotateX(p.x*3. + time);
    //pos.y += sin(pos.x) - sin(time/5.)*0.5 + cos(pos.y/3.1415)*0.5;
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.);
    
    gl_PointSize = 2.7;
    gl_Position.z = 0.0;
    c.rgb=vec3(1.0, 0.5, 0.0);
  }
`, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

shader(`
  precision highp float;
  varying vec3 c;
  void main(void) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(c, 1.);  
  }
`, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

let v = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "v");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(v, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(v);

let timeUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');


requestAnimationFrame(draw);
addEventListener('resize', resize)

function draw(t) {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.uniform1f(timeUniform, t/1000);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, vertices.length/2);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split("\n")
                   .map((str, i) => (""+(1+i))
                   .padStart(4, "0")+": "+str)
                   .join("\n"));
    throw message;
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="particle" />

<style>
    canvas {
        background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/HiAlf85.jpg);
    }
</style>
```

Second

```js
let vertices = [];
let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());

resize();

function resize() {
  
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = innerHeight;
  
  let step = 10,
      w = Math.floor(canvas.width/step), 
      h = Math.floor(canvas.height/step);
  
  vertices = [];
  for (var x=0; x<w*3; x++) 
    for (var y=0; y<10; y++) 
      vertices.push(1/w + x*10/w - 5, 1/h + y*2/h - 1)

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

let pid = gl.createProgram();

shader(`
  attribute vec2 v; 
  uniform float time; 
  varying vec3 c; 

  mat3 rotateX(float a) {
    return mat3(vec3( -1.0,     -1.0,    0.0), 
                vec3( 0.0,  cos(a), -sin(a)),
                vec3( 0.0,  sin(a),  cos(a)));
  }
  
  mat3 rotateY(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), 0.0, sin(a)), 
                vec3(    0.0, 1.0,    0.0),
                vec3(-sin(a), 0.0, cos(a)));
  }

  mat3 rotateZ(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), -sin(a),  0.0), 
                vec3( sin(a),  cos(a),  0.0),
                vec3(    0.0,     0.0,  1.0));
  }
  
  void main(void) {
    vec2 p = v;
    p.y += 0.3;
    p.x += sin(time/4. + p.y);
    vec3 pos = vec3(p.xy, 0.0)*rotateX(p.x*3. + time);
    //pos.y += sin(pos.x) - sin(time/5.)*0.5 + cos(pos.y/3.1415)*0.5;
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.);
    
    gl_PointSize = 2.7;
    gl_Position.z = 0.0;
    c.rgb=vec3(1., 0., 0.);
  }
`, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

shader(`
  precision highp float;
  varying vec3 c;
  void main(void) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(c, 1.);  
  }
`, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

let v = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "v");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(v, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(v);

let timeUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');


requestAnimationFrame(draw);
addEventListener('resize', resize)

function draw(t) {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.uniform1f(timeUniform, t/1000);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, vertices.length/2);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split("\n")
                   .map((str, i) => (""+(1+i))
                   .padStart(4, "0")+": "+str)
                   .join("\n"));
    throw message;
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" />

<style>
    canvas {
    background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/HiAlf85.jpg);
}
</style>
```

Tell me how to combine them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your CSS so the 2 canvases overlap and remove the background from the top canvas

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}

#particle {
  background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/HiAlf85.jpg);
}
#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Further, you need to figure out how to merge your 2 snippets. Just as a quick hack I surrounded both in their own functions so the variables don't conflict but that means a bunch of code is duplicated.

The final thing is a self closing canvas as in `<canvas />` is illegal HTML. You're required to use an actual closing tag as in `<canvas></canvas>`.

You can see this by inspecting

```html
<canvas />
<canvas />
```

in the browser's devtools

[image]

Notice one canvas is inside the other instead of them being separate. That's because the `/>` didn't actually end the canvas tag. Canvas tags don't display any HTML inside so the inner canvas is not displayed.

```js
'use strict';
(function() {
let vertices = [];
let gl = particle.getContext('webgl');
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());

resize();

function resize() {
  
  particle.width = innerWidth;
  particle.height = innerHeight;
  
  let step = 10,
      w = Math.floor(particle.width/step), 
      h = Math.floor(particle.height/step);
  
  vertices = [];
  for (var x=0; x<w*3; x++) 
    for (var y=0; y<10; y++) 
      vertices.push(1/w + x*10/w - 5, 1/h + y*2/h - 1)

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

let pid = gl.createProgram();

shader(`
  attribute vec2 v; 
  uniform float time; 
  varying vec3 c; 

  mat3 rotateX(float a) {
    return mat3(vec3( 1.0,     0.0,    0.0), 
                vec3( -1.0,  cos(a), -sin(a)),
                vec3( 0.0,  sin(a),  cos(a)));
  }
  
  mat3 rotateY(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), 0.0, sin(a)), 
                vec3(    0.0, 1.0,    0.0),
                vec3(-sin(a), 0.0, cos(a)));
  }

  mat3 rotateZ(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), -sin(a),  0.0), 
                vec3( sin(a),  cos(a),  0.0),
                vec3(    0.0,     0.0,  1.0));
  }
  
  void main(void) {
    vec2 p = v;
    p.y += 0.3;
    p.x += sin(time/4. + p.y);
    vec3 pos = vec3(p.xy, 0.0)*rotateX(p.x*3. + time);
    //pos.y += sin(pos.x) - sin(time/5.)*0.5 + cos(pos.y/3.1415)*0.5;
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.);
    
    gl_PointSize = 2.7;
    gl_Position.z = 0.0;
    c.rgb=vec3(1.0, 0.5, 0.0);
  }
`, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

shader(`
  precision highp float;
  varying vec3 c;
  void main(void) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(c, 1.);  
  }
`, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

let v = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "v");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(v, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(v);

let timeUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');


requestAnimationFrame(draw);
addEventListener('resize', resize)

function draw(t) {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.uniform1f(timeUniform, t/1000);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, vertices.length/2);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split("\n")
                   .map((str, i) => (""+(1+i))
                   .padStart(4, "0")+": "+str)
                   .join("\n"));
    throw message;
  }
}
}());

// ----------------------

(function() {
let vertices = [];
let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());

resize();

function resize() {
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = innerHeight;
  
  let step = 10,
      w = Math.floor(canvas.width/step), 
      h = Math.floor(canvas.height/step);
  
  vertices = [];
  for (var x=0; x<w*3; x++) 
    for (var y=0; y<10; y++) 
      vertices.push(1/w + x*10/w - 5, 1/h + y*2/h - 1)

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

let pid = gl.createProgram();

shader(`
  attribute vec2 v; 
  uniform float time; 
  varying vec3 c; 

  mat3 rotateX(float a) {
    return mat3(vec3( -1.0,     -1.0,    0.0), 
                vec3( 0.0,  cos(a), -sin(a)),
                vec3( 0.0,  sin(a),  cos(a)));
  }
  
  mat3 rotateY(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), 0.0, sin(a)), 
                vec3(    0.0, 1.0,    0.0),
                vec3(-sin(a), 0.0, cos(a)));
  }

  mat3 rotateZ(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), -sin(a),  0.0), 
                vec3( sin(a),  cos(a),  0.0),
                vec3(    0.0,     0.0,  1.0));
  }
  
  void main(void) {
    vec2 p = v;
    p.y += 0.3;
    p.x += sin(time/4. + p.y);
    vec3 pos = vec3(p.xy, 0.0)*rotateX(p.x*3. + time);
    //pos.y += sin(pos.x) - sin(time/5.)*0.5 + cos(pos.y/3.1415)*0.5;
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.);
    
    gl_PointSize = 2.7;
    gl_Position.z = 0.0;
    c.rgb=vec3(1., 0., 0.);
  }
`, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

shader(`
  precision highp float;
  varying vec3 c;
  void main(void) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(c, 1.);  
  }
`, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

let v = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "v");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(v, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(v);

let timeUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');


requestAnimationFrame(draw);
addEventListener('resize', resize)

function draw(t) {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.uniform1f(timeUniform, t/1000);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, vertices.length/2);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split("\n")
                   .map((str, i) => (""+(1+i))
                   .padStart(4, "0")+": "+str)
                   .join("\n"));
    throw message;
  }
}
}());
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}

#particle {
  background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/HiAlf85.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="particle"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Of course it's not clear why you'd want to do this. Things would likely be faster to use 1 canvas but I'll assume you have your reasons.

```js
'use strict';
let vertices = [];
let gl = particle.getContext('webgl');
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());

resize();

function resize() {
  
  particle.width = innerWidth;
  particle.height = innerHeight;
  
  let step = 10,
      w = Math.floor(particle.width/step), 
      h = Math.floor(particle.height/step);
  
  vertices = [];
  for (var x=0; x<w*3; x++) 
    for (var y=0; y<10; y++) 
      vertices.push(1/w + x*10/w - 5, 1/h + y*2/h - 1)    

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

let pid1 = createProgram(`
  attribute vec2 v; 
  uniform float time; 
  varying vec3 c; 

  mat3 rotateX(float a) {
    return mat3(vec3( 1.0,     0.0,    0.0), 
                vec3( -1.0,  cos(a), -sin(a)),
                vec3( 0.0,  sin(a),  cos(a)));
  }
  
  mat3 rotateY(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), 0.0, sin(a)), 
                vec3(    0.0, 1.0,    0.0),
                vec3(-sin(a), 0.0, cos(a)));
  }

  mat3 rotateZ(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), -sin(a),  0.0), 
                vec3( sin(a),  cos(a),  0.0),
                vec3(    0.0,     0.0,  1.0));
  }
  
  void main(void) {
    vec2 p = v;
    p.y += 0.3;
    p.x += sin(time/4. + p.y);
    vec3 pos = vec3(p.xy, 0.0)*rotateX(p.x*3. + time);
    //pos.y += sin(pos.x) - sin(time/5.)*0.5 + cos(pos.y/3.1415)*0.5;
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.);
    
    gl_PointSize = 2.7;
    gl_Position.z = 0.0;
    c.rgb=vec3(1.0, 0.5, 0.0);
  }
`,
`
  precision highp float;
  varying vec3 c;
  void main(void) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(c, 1.);  
  }
`);

let pid2 = createProgram(`
  attribute vec2 v; 
  uniform float time; 
  varying vec3 c; 

  mat3 rotateX(float a) {
    return mat3(vec3( -1.0,     -1.0,    0.0), 
                vec3( 0.0,  cos(a), -sin(a)),
                vec3( 0.0,  sin(a),  cos(a)));
  }
  
  mat3 rotateY(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), 0.0, sin(a)), 
                vec3(    0.0, 1.0,    0.0),
                vec3(-sin(a), 0.0, cos(a)));
  }

  mat3 rotateZ(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), -sin(a),  0.0), 
                vec3( sin(a),  cos(a),  0.0),
                vec3(    0.0,     0.0,  1.0));
  }
  
  void main(void) {
    vec2 p = v;
    p.y += 0.3;
    p.x += sin(time/4. + p.y);
    vec3 pos = vec3(p.xy, 0.0)*rotateX(p.x*3. + time);
    //pos.y += sin(pos.x) - sin(time/5.)*0.5 + cos(pos.y/3.1415)*0.5;
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.);
    
    gl_PointSize = 2.7;
    gl_Position.z = 0.0;
    c.rgb=vec3(1., 0., 0.);
  }
`, `
  precision highp float;
  varying vec3 c;
  void main(void) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(c, 1.);  
  }
`);

let v1 = gl.getAttribLocation(pid1, "v");
let timeUniform1 = gl.getUniformLocation(pid1, 'time');

let v2 = gl.getAttribLocation(pid2, "v");
let timeUniform2 = gl.getUniformLocation(pid2, 'time');

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
addEventListener('resize', resize)

function draw(t) {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  
  gl.useProgram(pid1);
  // normally you'd bind a buffer here but since you only
  // have one and the vertex data is the same for both programs
  // we don't need to bind a different buffer
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(v1, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(v1);   
  gl.uniform1f(timeUniform1, t/1000);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, vertices.length/2);
  
  gl.useProgram(pid2);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(v2, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(v2);   
  gl.uniform1f(timeUniform2, t/1000);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, vertices.length/2);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function createProgram(vs, fs) {
  const pid = gl.createProgram();
  shader(vs, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, pid);
  shader(fs, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, pid);
  gl.linkProgram(pid);
  // should check for link error here!
  return pid;
}

function shader(src, type, pid) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split("\n")
                   .map((str, i) => (""+(1+i))
                   .padStart(4, "0")+": "+str)
                   .join("\n"));
    throw message;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
#particle {
  background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/HiAlf85.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="particle"></canvas>
```

Comment: It's very strong. Thnx.

Comment: `Of course it's not clear why you'd want to do this. Things would likely be faster to use 1 canvas but I'll assume you have your reasons.` It is necessary that two planes move towards each other, as if they were independent. I have not figured out how to do this in one canvas. And on the example site, two canvases are used.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how to implement this on one. If it's real, of course.

Comment: See [this maybe](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-multiple-things.html)?

Comment: Not bad. It will be necessary to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you go on the website you linked and take a peak at their code, you will notice that they are simply placing both canvas inside the same div, and placing them on top of each other with a bit of css

```css
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -1px;
}
```

Comment: Yes I know. But what about js? Only the second is displayed.

Comment: You are using a background image, you need to keep the background transparent if you want to see what's behind. At least for the background of the one in front.

Comment: Yes. But only the second script is displayed. It is also necessary to display the first one. https://codepen.io/m0nte-cr1st0/pen/WVJobE?editors=0010

Comment: You are using the same names for the methods and variables of both canvas. Both contexts are defined as `gl`, so you are pretty much deleting the first one as soon as the second one is defined.

Answer (score 0):

In the linked example, the two canvases are overlaid on each other due to absolute positioning.

But with your example, even if you positioned them over each other, you'd only see one because you add a non-transparent background image to each canvas.

The linked example depends on each canvas to be transparent. That means, only colour the pixels in the canvas that need to be coloured, and no background colours or images unless there is transparency.

Comment: And if make the second (or first) canvas with the background color and set it to transparency?

Comment: As long as the top canvas has some element of transparency, you should be able to see through to the bottom one. The bottom canvas is not required to be transparent unless you need to see through that one too.

Comment: But only the second script is displayed. It is also necessary to display the first one.

Comment: You overwrite your variables. Since you reuse `gl` and other variables between the two, only one ends up getting updated because you lose all the references to the previous webgl context.